# Blackberry Fixed Header and Footer in Webworks

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, iscroll

Is there any way to create a fixed header and footer in Webworks for Blackberry Phones 6.0+?

I tried using iScroll - works fine on Tablet OS but not on BlackBerries, it works fine in the browser but stops workings when "compiled".

It seems anything with position: absolute; will shrink the entire page down.

```
Header <- absolute
Content <- normal
Footer <- absolute
```

For some reason the entire page shrinks down to 40ish pixels (the height of the header)

both html and body have height at 100% and content div is outside the header:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: tried jquery mobile one?

Comment: I could but JQuery Mobile seems to be a lot of code for no reason - using Zepto at the moment.

Comment: Zepto got any fixed header solution?

Comment: Nop - unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BB 6 browser fixing header and footer with absolute/fixed position is buggy. When you scroll positioned elements move along with page. When you stop scrolling it back to top / bottom as per the position. I would suggest using javascript to find the height of the device & fix them.

```
 #header{
  height:50px;
}

#footer{
  height:50px;
}
```

JS

```
    function setHeight(){
    width = screen.availWidth;
    height = screen.availHeight;
    $('#content').height(height-100);   
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I tested on bb simulator OS6 and OS5, when I scroll up or down the content inside the "#content" doesn't move.

Comment: Try #content{overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}